# Google OAuth Suddenly Not Working AFNetworkingErrorDomain

Tags: ios, oauth, google-oauth

This past week the Google OAuth portion of my iOS app has completely stopped working out of nowhere. The user enters their details into the custom login field within the app, which then authorizes with Google, creates a token, and should tell them that their login has been successful (within the app). Instead, they are seeing a Login Failed message.  I cannot seem to figure out why (did Google change something??) but the error code I am getting when users try to login is the following:

```
        2013-10-27 12:49:56.137 XXXX [1210:1a003] URL is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=1e543c0fe20b1da5&hl=en_GB&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUm1LHD2mXAhs8QexAFwlf9KVIt5UdNj_
    2013-10-27 12:49:57.776 XXXX[1210:1a003] 333
    2013-10-27 12:49:57.776 XXXX[1210:1a003] Failed: -1011
    2013-10-27 12:49:57.777 XXXX[1210:1a003] Description: Error
Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" 
UserInfo=0x96b5700 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 
4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><title>Google 
Accounts</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta 
name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-
scale=1, user-scalable=0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><link 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/1893590695-error_page_css_ltr.css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/708588620-common_lib.js"></script>
    <style>@media screen and (max-width:500px) {#robot {background: none; min-height: 0; min-width: 0; padding: 0;}#stack_trace {display: none;}}
    #oauth2_request_info_header {background-image: url("https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/blank.gif");}</style></head><body ><div id="robot"></div><a href="//www.google.com/" id="googlelogo"><img src="//www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif" alt="Google"></a><p class="large"><b>400.</b> <ins>That's an error.</ins></p><p class="large">The page that you requested is invalid.  <ins>That's all we know.</ins></p></body></html>, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=1e543c0fe20b1da5&hl=en_GB&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUm1LHD2mXAhs8QexAFwlf9KVIt5UdNj_>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=1e543c0fe20b1da5&hl=en_GB&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUm1LHD2mXAhs8QexAFwlf9KVIt5UdNj_, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x96aae40>}
```

Here are the parts of the code that seem to be causing the error:

```
-(void)doSignInStep2:(NSString*)response
{
   // NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", response);

    NSString *form = [response substringFromIndex:[response rangeOfString:@"form "].location];
    form = [form substringToIndex:[form rangeOfString:@"</form>"].location];

    NSString *formAction = [form substringFromIndex:[form rangeOfString:@"action="].location + 8];
    formAction = [formAction substringToIndex:[formAction rangeOfString:@"\""].location];

    if ([formAction rangeOfString:@"'"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        formAction = [formAction substringToIndex:[formAction rangeOfString:@"'"].location];
    }


    formAction = [formAction stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];

    //get all input elements in the form
    NSMutableArray *elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSRange rng = [form rangeOfString:@"<input "];

    while (rng.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *inputItem = [form substringFromIndex:rng.location];
        NSInteger *inputItemLength = [inputItem rangeOfString:@">"].location + 1;
        inputItem = [inputItem substringToIndex:inputItemLength];

        NSString *elementName = nil;
        NSString *elementValue = nil;

        NSRange iiRange = [inputItem rangeOfString:@"name=\""];

        if (iiRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            elementName = [inputItem substringFromIndex:iiRange.location + 6];
            elementName = [elementName substringToIndex:[elementName rangeOfString:@"\""].location];
        }

        iiRange = [inputItem rangeOfString:@"value=\""];

        if (iiRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            elementValue = [inputItem substringFromIndex:iiRange.location + 7];
            elementValue = [elementValue substringToIndex:[elementValue rangeOfString:@"\""].location];

            elementValue = [elementValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
        }

        if (elementName && elementValue) {
            NSString *encodedstring = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                                   (__bridge CFStringRef)elementValue,
                                                                                                   NULL,
                                                                                                   (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                                   kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

            if (![elementName isEqualToString:@"submit_access"])
                [elements addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:elementName, encodedstring, nil]];
        }

        form = [form substringFromIndex:rng.location];

        form = [form substringFromIndex:inputItemLength];

        rng = [form rangeOfString:@"<input "];
    }

    [elements addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"submit_access", @"true", nil]];


    NSString *params = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i < [elements count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *element = [elements objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([params length] > 0)
            params = [params stringByAppendingString:@"&"];

        params = [params stringByAppendingString:[element objectAtIndex:0]];
        params = [params stringByAppendingString:@"="];
        params = [params stringByAppendingString:[element objectAtIndex:1]];
    }

    //NSLog(@"Params: %@", params);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:formAction];
    NSLog(@"URL is %@", url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //[request setValue:[params length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op3 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [op3 setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:  ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [self doSignInStep3:response];


    }failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"333");
         NSLog(@"Failed: %d", error.code);
         NSLog(@"Description: %@", error.description);

         //NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


         [self.delegate finishedSignIn:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] response:nil];
     }];

    [op3 start];

}
```

and...

```
-(void)doSignInStep3:(NSString*)response
{
    //NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);


    //<input id="code" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="4/Zvd-PjWHw53BqdSzExYus1MsT9dx.snLL4gUE1cocOl05ti8ZT3bZAne4dgI"
    if ([response rangeOfString:@"<input id=\""].location == NSNotFound)
    {

        [self.delegate finishedSignIn:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] response:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *code = [response substringFromIndex:[response rangeOfString:@"<input id=\""].location];

        code = [code substringFromIndex:[code rangeOfString:@"value=\""].location + 7];

        code = [code substringToIndex:[code rangeOfString:@"\""].location];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        //NSLog(@"Code: %@", code);

        NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@", code];
        params = [params stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&client_id=%@", client_id]];
        params = [params stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&client_secret=%@", client_secret]];
        params = [params stringByAppendingString:@"&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob"];
        params = [params stringByAppendingString:@"&grant_type=authorization_code"];
        //params = [params stringByAppendingString:@"&approval_prompt=force"];

        [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op4 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [op4 setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:  ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            //NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);

            [self processResponse:response];

            [self.delegate finishedSignIn:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] response:response];

        }failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"444");
             NSLog(@"Failed: %d", error.code);
             NSLog(@"Description: %@", error.description);

             //NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

             [self.delegate finishedSignIn:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] response:nil];
         }];

        [op4 start];


    }
}
```

I am at a complete loss here because everything was totally fine previously and nothing was touched on my end. What would cause this to completely stop working? I've already tried new client_id and client_secret codes and they produce the same error. Any type of insight would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error page that you included in your logs, I see

```
The page that you requested is invalid. That's all we know.
```

My app is a webserver app, but I often see the same error page thrown up during authorisation.  In my case, I simply Back and retry.

My working assumption is that it's a transient exception thrown somewhere in Google's infrastructure, which materialises in a misleading/meaningless error message.

So for your app, all I can suggest is that you somehow capture that situation and retry the login.